# Different font size for every label in geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a  bar plot made using `ggplot2`. I want to add label to each bar using `geom_text` such that the text size of the label is corresponds to the label. To do so I used the following code:

```
a <- aggregate(mpg ~ vs + am , mtcars, function(i) round(mean(i)))
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(vs), y=mpg, fill=factor(am))) + 
      geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge") + 
      geom_text(data = a, aes(label = mpg, size = mpg), 
                position = position_dodge(width=0.9))
```

This gave me a plot which looks like this:
[image]

As you can see the label sizes are changing but the texts font size does not correspond to the size of the label. For the first bar the label is 15 and it is hardly visible. When I plot the same barplot with fixed text size as 15 the label is not as small as seen above. Following is the code and the plot generated using a fixed text size:

```
 a <- aggregate(mpg ~ vs + am , mtcars, function(i) round(mean(i)))

 p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(vs), y=mpg, fill=factor(am))) + 
      geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge") + 
      geom_text(data = a, aes(label = mpg), 
                position = position_dodge(width=0.9), size = 15)
```

[image]

Is there a way to make the size of the label consistent when different sizes are given for each label?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the range for `scale_size`.

For example, if you want the scaled sizes to range from font size 15 to font size 28:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(vs), y=mpg, fill=factor(am))) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") + 
  geom_text(data = a, aes(label = mpg, size = mpg), 
            position = position_dodge(width=0.9)) +
  scale_size(range = c(15, 28), guide = F) #legend hidden
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Setting size to `sort(a$mpg)` does the trick

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(vs), y=mpg, fill=factor(am))) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge") + 
    geom_text(data = a, aes(label = mpg), 
              position = position_dodge(width=0.9), size = sort(a$mpg))
```

[image: snap1]

Comment: In your answer the text size between 20 and 21 seems to be interchanged. Maybe its because the data is in the order `15 21 20 28` ?

Comment: @SBista, indeed correct, order in `a$mpg` is `15 21 20 28`, have updated ans. accordingly